# How to sort Json Api data?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to sort a list by date from data that I get from JSON API. The JSON is a Map that is serialized into a model. I tried a couple of things but none of them worked. Any idea how to go about this? Not sure if I should sort it in Listview.builder or in the API request class.

API request class

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/events/models/events.dart';



class EventApi {
  static var client = http.Client();


  static Future<Event?> fetchEvents() async {
    final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://xposure.ae/wp-json/wp/auditorium/v1/events'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonString = response.body;
      return eventFromJson(jsonString);
    } else {
      //show error message
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Model class

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Event eventFromJson(String str) => Event.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String eventToJson(Event data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Event {
  Event({
    @required this.data,
  });

  List<Datum>? data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    data!.sort((a, b) => a.datetime.compareTo(b.datetime));
  }


  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Datum {
  Datum({
    required this.eventtitle,
    required this.description,
    required this.eventImage,
    required this.speaker,
    required this.datetime,
    required this.location,
  });

  String eventtitle;
  String description;
  String eventImage;
  Speaker? speaker;
  String datetime;
  Location? location;


  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
    eventtitle: json["Eventtitle"] == null ? null : json["Eventtitle"],
    description: json["Description"] == null ? null : json["Description"],
    eventImage: json["event_image"] == null ? null : json["event_image"],
    speaker: json["Speaker"] == null ? null : Speaker.fromJson(json["Speaker"]),
    datetime: json["datetime"] == null ? null : json["datetime"],
    location: json["Location"] == null ? null : Location.fromJson(json["Location"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "Eventtitle": eventtitle == null ? null : eventtitle,
    "Description": description == null ? null : description,
    "event_image": eventImage == null ? null : eventImage,
    "Speaker": speaker == null ? null : speaker!.toJson(),
    "datetime": datetime == null ? null : datetime,
    "Location": location == null ? null : location!.toJson(),
  };
}

class Location {
  Location({
    required this.venue,
    required this.address,
  });

  Venue? venue;
  Address? address;

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location(
    venue: json["venue"] == null ? null : venueValues.map[json["venue"]],
    address: json["address"] == null ? null : addressValues.map[json["address"]],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "venue": venue == null ? null : venueValues.reverse[venue],
    "address": address == null ? null : addressValues.reverse[address],
  };
}

enum Address { SHARJAH_BR_SHARJAH_BR_61110_BR_UNITED_ARAB_EMIRATES }

final addressValues = EnumValues({
  "Sharjah</br>Sharjah,</br>61110,</br>United Arab Emirates": Address.SHARJAH_BR_SHARJAH_BR_61110_BR_UNITED_ARAB_EMIRATES
});

enum Venue { XPOSURE_INTERNATIONAL_PHOTOGRAPHY_FESTIVAL }

final venueValues = EnumValues({
  "Xposure International Photography Festival": Venue.XPOSURE_INTERNATIONAL_PHOTOGRAPHY_FESTIVAL
});

class Speaker {
  Speaker({
    required this.speakername,
    required this.link,
  });

  String speakername;
  String link;

  factory Speaker.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Speaker(
    speakername: json["speakername"] == null ? null : json["speakername"],
    link: json["link"] == null ? null : json["link"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "speakername": speakername == null ? null : speakername,
    "link": link == null ? null : link,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

Even view class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/instance_manager.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/events/views/event_details.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/events/controllers/events_controller.dart';
import 'package:lets_chat/app/modules/events/views/event_tile.dart';

class EventView extends StatelessWidget {
  final EventsController eventController = Get.put(EventsController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
        elevation: 2,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Obx(() {
              if (eventController.isLoading.value)
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ));
              else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: eventController.event.value!.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventDetails(event: eventController.event.value!.data![index]))
                          );
                        },
                          child: EventTile(eventController.event.value!.data![index]));
                    });
              }
            }),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to sort the data from the JSON API.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Events",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xffffffff),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: [
          TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.refresh,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if (ascend) {
                  sortAscending(); //to sort the date from oldest to latest
                } else {
                  sortDescending(); //to sort the date from latest to oldest
                }
              },
              label: Text(
                "Sort by date",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.black),
              ))
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
          child: Column(
            children: _buildList(),
          ),
        ),
      )),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
);
```

}

The code below can help you build an array of widgets

```
 List<Widget> _buildList() {
List<Widget> x = [];

//jsonData refers to the data from the JSON API
 //sort the jsonData here before the loop by calling either the sortAscending() function or sortDescending() function.

sortDescending(); //from latest date to oldest

for (int i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  DateTime dateTime =
      DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - kk:mm").parse(jsonData[i]['datetime']);

  x.add(
    Row(children: [
      Flex(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Text(months[dateTime.month - 1].toString(),
                style:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14)),
            Card(
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
                    Text(
                      dateTime.day.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Color(0xff800200),
                          fontSize: 22),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Text(
                        dateTime.year.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
                      ),
                    )
                  ])),
            ),
          ]),
      Flexible(
        child: Card(
          semanticContainer: true,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          child: Container(
            height: 200,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(jsonData[i]['event_image']),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25), BlendMode.dstATop),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 5),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(jsonData[i]['Eventtitle'],
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.pin_drop,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        jsonData[i]['Location']['venue'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          elevation: 5,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        ),
      )
    ]),
  );
}

return x;
```

}

The functions below will help in updating the list as you sort by date with the action button on the AppBar

```
  sortAscending() {
setState(() {
  ascend = false; //initialize this bool variable at the top of the class.
  jsonData.sort((a, b) => DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - kk:mm")
      .parse(b['datetime'])
      .compareTo(DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - kk:mm").parse(a['datetime'])));
});
```

}

```
  sortDescending() {
setState(() {
  ascend = true;
  jsonData.sort((a, b) => DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - kk:mm")
      .parse(a['datetime'])
      .compareTo(DateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy - kk:mm").parse(b['datetime'])));
});
```

}

You'll use below to format the name of the months.

```
List months = [  'JAN',  'FEB',  'MAR',  'APR',  'MAY',  'JUN',  'JUL',  'AUG', 'SEP',  'OCT',  'NOV',  'DEC'];
```

Here are screenshots that illustrate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer that solved it for me. Would you know how could I set it up that the list is already sorted by date when users goes into that Event page?

Comment: Hi @Quentinio, yes that's possible. I have updated the _buildList() function. Right before the for loop there is a code added to sort the list before display. Also kindly upvote my answers. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to upvote but I'm not high level enough :/

Comment: Cool, I understood.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are storing your dates as `String` in your Model class.

It then gets sorted alphabetically:

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> dates = [
    "September 14, 2022 - 2:35 PM",
    "February 24, 2022 - 3:05 AM",
    "February 3, 2022 - 10:10 AM",
    "January 13, 2022 - 9:15 PM"
  ];
  dates.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  dates.forEach(print);
}

// Dates get sorted alphabetically:
// February 24, 2022 - 3:05 pm
// February 3, 2022 - 10:10 pm
// January 13, 2022 - 9:15 pm
// September 14, 2022 - 2:35 pm
```

If this is the problem you face, you should probably convert them to `DateTime` objects either in your `sort` or (probably better) in your `fromJson` conversion.

Simple example:

```dart
void main2() {
  List<DateTime> dates = [
    "September 14, 2022 - 2:35 PM",
    "February 24, 2022 - 3:05 AM",
    "February 3, 2022 - 10:10 AM",
    "January 13, 2022 - 9:15 PM"
  ].map((d) => DateFormat('MMMM d, y - h:mm a').parse(d)).toList();
  dates.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
  dates.forEach(print);
}

// Dates get sorted chronologically:
// 2022-01-13 21:15:00.000
// 2022-02-03 10:10:00.000
// 2022-02-24 03:05:00.000
// 2022-09-14 14:35:00.000
```